# Table with enumerated rows except the last one

Tags: html, css

How can I have a table with numerated rows except the last row? I was trying below code but it does not work :(

**EDIT:** *Below code works in Chrome and Firefox but not in Safari. I don't know about IE yet*

```css
table.enumerated {
    counter-reset: rowNumber;
}

table.enumerated > tbody > tr {
    counter-increment: rowNumber;
}

table.enumerated > tbody > tr > td:first-child::before {
    content: counter(rowNumber);
    min-width: 1em;
}
table.enumerated > tbody > tr:last-child > td:first-child::before {
    content: unset;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" class="enumerated">
    <tr>
        <td></td><td>one</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td><td>two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td><td>three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='no-number'></td><td>no number</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: How exactly does it not work? The snippet looks like it does what you want.

Comment: Oh!, you are right. I just realised it works in Chrome and Firefox but not Safari. Do you have a work around for Safari?

Comment: @nacho4d: Actually, I am on Chrome v38 and it shows the counter value in the last row also, so it is not universally working in Chrome also. Maybe they fixed something in the recent versions.

Comment: Which version of Safari?

Comment: I am in Safari 8.0.7 and still see the last row number 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using `:not(:last-child)` on the tr, then you won't need the `unset` or `none` trick.

```css
table.enumerated {
    counter-reset: rowNumber;
}

table.enumerated > tbody > tr {
    counter-increment: rowNumber;
}

table.enumerated > tbody > tr:not(:last-child) > td:first-child::before {
    content: counter(rowNumber);
    min-width: 1em;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" class="enumerated">
    <tr>
        <td></td><td>one</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td><td>two</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td><td>three</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class='no-number'></td><td>no number</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Unfortunately, Safari 5.1.7 is the only version I can test on. Yes, I know. But it even works there!

Comment: Given that `:not` doesn't actually cause any degradation of browser support (as `last-child` was anyway used), this is the better option.

Comment: @Harry I hope so. I can never remember how good browser support is for those "newer" features without looking it up. Also, if it seems I'm trying to dis the other answers, sorry about that. Not my intention! This is just the first thing I thought to try.

Comment: @MrLister: Ofcourse not mate :) It is always good to post better answers as well as provide as many options as possible for OP to choose based on their needs. Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

You should use `content: none;` as the [browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/unset#compat-desktop) for unset is not warranted. It works fine in Chrome and Firefox but not in IE, Safari and Opera.

```
table.enumerated > tbody > tr:last-child > td:first-child::before {
    content: none;
}
```